# changing the color the tkinter title bar on macOS

Tags: python, macos, tkinter

I have an app and want to change the color of the title bar. I can do that on windows with the following code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from ctypes import windll, byref, sizeof, c_int

root = tk.Tk()
root.update()

HWND = windll.user32.GetParent(root.winfo_id()) 
DWMWA_ATTRIBUTE = 35
COLOR = 0x000000FF # hex order: 0x00bbggrr

windll.dwmapi.DwmSetWindowAttribute(HWND, DWMWA_ATTRIBUTE, byref(c_int(COLOR)), sizeof(c_int))

root.mainloop()
```

Now I want to do the same for macOS. Sadly, windll.user32 only exists on windows, so is there a mac specific way of approaching this?

(I know I can hide the title bar with overrideredirect but I don't want to use that because it causes other weird behavior)

Comment: You mentioned weird behaviour when using `overrideredirect`, what exactly do you mean? If you mean that the window disappears from the taskbar, look at [this](https://github.com/TheLizzard/BetterTk/blob/main/src/bettertk/notitlebartk_x11.py). It should work on Linux/MacOS as long as it has `x11` - only tested on Ubuntu.

Comment: That does seem really useful, I just tried it on windows and it does give me a proper window without a title bar. However, it doesn't seem to work with customtkinter (I replaced the tk objects in the NoTitlebarTk class with the customtk equivalents. But when I try to add widgets I get "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'master'")

Comment: I only made it work with `tkinter`. I never actually used `customtkinter` so I don't know what is causing the problem. If you look at the code, the `_overrideredirect` method is the one removing the titlebar while leaving the window in the taskbar. If you somehow embed that into `customtkinter`, you might get it to work. Btw feel free to browse the github repository, there is code similar code for windows, and code for resizing the window. Most of the comments might be outdated

Comment: I am aware of that, the problem is that doing that will break a lot of the functionality of the window (no preview when switching tasks, no window snapping etc)